# set a shell variable in make to use later on the same line

Tags: makefile, sh

if you do this in sh:

```
ABC=123 && echo value is ${ABC}
```

you get this

```
value is 123
```

and if you put this in a `makefile`:

```
main:
    echo value is ${ABC}
```

(except don't copy paste that because my tab is actually four spaces)

and then pass it into the file like this:

```
$ ABC=123 make main
echo value is 123
value is 123
```

everything works as expected

but I would like to set the sh variable on the same line *inside* the makefile

```
main:
    ABC=123 && echo value is ${ABC}
```

and I get this:

```
$ make main
ABC=123 && echo value is 
value is
```

How can I set a shell variable?

---

I am trying to do this because I am sourcing a file.. this is just a minimal example of thing thing that I thought would work that doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the variable is expanded by `make` not shell. You can tell it by the very first line that prints echo without `${ABC}`. You need to quote the dollar sign if you want to pass it to shell, e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
main:
        ABC=123 && echo value is $${ABC}

$ make main
ABC=123 && echo value is ${ABC}
value is 123
```

Comment: oooh - I was looking for the problem on the setting the variable side! thank you so much!  ${} looks for shell vars, but it is still make that does it!!!

Comment: There is a great page: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Make.html#Variables_in_Makefiles